# Creating a common controller class for zend modular structure

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using the zend modular structure for a project. I have below directory structure

```
 application/
   modules/
    default/
        controllers/
            IndexController.php
            FooController.php
        models/
        views/
            scripts/
                index/
                foo/
            helpers/
            filters/
    blog/
        controllers/
            IndexController.php
        models/
        views/
            scripts/
                index/
            helpers/
            filters/
    news/
        controllers/
            IndexController.php
            ListController.php
        models/
        views/
            scripts/
                index/
                list/
            helpers/
            filters/
```

I want to create a common controller class to which I would extend in all module's controller

e.g I wan t to create a class like below

```
 class My_Common extends Zend_Controller_Action 
 {

  public function init()
  {
    
  }
}
```

In all module's controller I wan tto extend it like

```
 class News_IndexController extends My_Common
 {
     public function init()
 {
    
 }

 }
```

How could I achieve this? I tried to create it in Default controller but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this by adding a namespace of my to the library folder. And if you work with the zend library in mind the folder structure would look like this:

```
the_common_folder_structure/ 
.../
library/
    zend/
    myNamespace/
      Controller/
        Common.php
```

Then in your modules just extend the MyNamespace_Controller_Common.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is add a "My" folder within the library directory and then replicate Zends class structure, eg :

Create the file

library/My/Controller/Action.php with the classname: My_Controller_Action

Make sure you include : autoloaderNamespaces.my = "My_" in your application.ini file, this includes the My directory to your autoloader.

You should then be able to extend My_Controller_Action from anyone of your module controllers.